# Truncate SQL Compact Database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, truncate

I have a SQL Compact 4.0 installed on my System and I am using it with VS2012. On VS2012, i have SQL Server Compact/SQLite toolbox extension installed.

This extension gives various options i don't find any truncate table option. Query `truncate table tblTransaction` doesn't seem to be working. I tried `delete` query but it doesn't reset the start point. I have a option to Drop and Recreate the table using extension to delete content as well as reset the Identity Column start.

My question is :

> Is there any way to truncate SQL Server Compact database. I have about
>   65 tables in database and i need to truncate the whole database. Not just delete the data but to reset the start point of Auto Increment column.

Comment: When you try to truncate do you get any errors? Do the credentials you are using have enough authority to do a truncate?

Comment: Actually `Truncate` keyword isn't supported in SQL CE so there's the error. And yes, i have admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You can reseed the IDENTITY value by running this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTableName] ALTER COLUMN [Id] IDENTITY (1, 1)
```

In addition I have created this feature proposal, feel free to vote (or even contribute) https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/workitem/12109

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't want to alter each and every table individually. Plus i read a article which states **If an identity seed has been set then the `Alter Table` doesn't work perfectly.**

Comment: Link? This is your only option, SQL Compact does NOT have a TRUNCATE command

Comment: [](http://blog.michaelhidalgo.info/2012/11/truncate-table-statement-is-not-allowed.html) Please see in comment. 

Isn't there any way to use `delete` and `alter` commands to flush the database with counter reset ?

Comment: @Mahadev You could write a SP to delete and alter all your tables... then you just need to run the SP once.

Comment: Yep. But can it be used to truncate all table at once ? If yes, please tell me how to.